# How to initialize Pango under Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, fonts, pango

Having downloaded Pango and GLib from the GTK+ Project's Win32 downloads [page](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) and having created and configured a Win32 project under Visual Studio 2005 so it points to the proper *lib* and *include* directories, how do you initialize Pango for rendering to a Win32 window?

Should the first call be to **pango_win32_get_context()**? Calling that function causes the application to hang on that call, as the function never returns.

What should be the first call? What other calls are needed to initialize Pango for Win32 and render a simple text string? Are there any examples available online for rendering with Pango under Win32?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pango is a GObject based library.  As such, you need to make sure that the glib dynamic type system is initialized before using any of its functionality.  This can be done by calling [`g_type_init()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html#g-type-init) (either directly or indirectly via something like `gtk_init()`).  Could this be your problem?

Comment: Thanks. That took care of the problem with hanging on the call to pango_win32_get_context(). Now to see if I can render some text. Additional advice is welcome.